# Expected value of a delta function

Tags: probability, expected-value, density-function, dirac-delta

I have a certain question concerning the expected value of a density function, which is given by a delta function: If
$$ f(x)= \frac{k}{m}\cdot \delta_{q}(x)$$
defines a density function, with $k,m$ being constants and
$$\delta_q(x)\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  \infty & ,\, x=q \\
  0 & ,\,\text{else} \\
 \end{array}
 \right. $$
being the delta function at $q$. Then the expected value is given by
$$\frac{k}{m}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\cdot \delta_q(x)\, \text{d}x \,.$$

Is there any clever way to calculate this expected value? I don't really know how to handle the delta function. Should one use integration by parts?

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: What does $d$ mean in $\delta_q(d)$?  Did you mean $x$?  If so, just use the definition of the delta function.

Comment: if this is a probability distribution then $k/m=1$

Comment: @lulu it was a typo.. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

By the [definition of the $\delta$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#As_a_measure), for all continous functions $\phi$:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x)\delta_q(x)dx = \phi(q)$$

Thus, the expected value of $f$ is $\frac{k}{m}q$.